# Creating class union in Jena

Tags: union, jena, semantic-web

I'm trying to create [UnionClass](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/UnionClass.html) of two classes using Jena framework.

I currently have the following code

```
 RDFNode[] nodes1 = {apple, banana};
 RDFList fruit_list= model.createList(nodes1);

 UnionClass fruit_union= model.createUnionClass(NS + "Fruit_Union", fruist_list);
```

I got this code from somewhere on the internet as an example but somehow this does not generate the necessary code that I want.

How would I go about creating a union of two classes or resources then use it as a range for a ObjectProperty?

Comment: but somehow this does not generate the necessary code that I want."  How do you know?  What *does* it create? What were you expecting it to create?  Please note that "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."  I think you've got the code, but we don't know what you're trying to achieve and what didn't work about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the result you expect. However please check the below solution.

```
public void unionClassObjectProperty(){
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
    String NS = "http://example.com/q/123456/";
    //creating a union of two classes
    OntClass apple = model.createClass( NS+"apple" );
    OntClass banana = model.createClass( NS+"banana" );
    OntClass fruit_union = model.createUnionClass( null, model.createList( new RDFNode[] { apple, banana } ));
    //use it as a range for a ObjectProperty
    ObjectProperty objectProperty = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"fruitObjectProperty");
    objectProperty.addRange(fruit_union);
    model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
}
```